# Allow mail from logged in contact - CiviSpark

Tags: civimail

We're using civispark with civimail and want to be able to send mail from the logged in user. I have found this setting but I don't seem to have the option to amend it. Administer>Settings>Outbound Mail Does anyone know if that is a CiviSpark 'thing' or if I should be looking elsewhere to change it to yes? TIA

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try asking in the Spark channel on https://chat.civicrm.org

Comment: As an update: CiviCRM Spark have confirmed that this isn't currently possible on that platform.

Comment: Ok, please add that as an answer and accept it (green tick) so others know the question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM Spark have confirmed that this isn't currently possible on that platform.